# export json to xls doc in java/ js

Tags: javascript, java, json, csv

I'm trying to export json data into an Excel file. My json is not consistent which is why I have problem because the excel mapping is all scattered and the columns are messed up. Here is a sample JSON I'm working on:

```
[
{
"path": "/conte/nt",
"title": "First",
"date": "January 14, 2015 8:59:57 PM EST"
},
{
"path": "/content/o",
"title": "Third Annual",
"date": "January 14, 2015 8:59:57 PM EST"
},
{
"path": "/co/en",
"title": "Motivating Factors",
"date": "January 14, 2015 8:59:57 PM EST"
 },
 {
"path": "/con/ent",
"title": "Meeting",
"description": "test",
"date": "January 14, 2015 8:59:57 PM EST",
"key": "xyz, abc"
}
]
```

Comment: What format do you want? We can't answer any IO questions without that info. Also, how is this inconsistent? Because one object has a few extra keys? In JavaScript you can demystify which Object you're looking at with a simple `if(Object.keys(array[i]).indexOf('key') !== -1)` (i.e., you've iterated to the last object).